# ReactJs Button won't fire on desktop configuration but it works fine in mobile configuration

Tags: reactjs, button, axios, modal-dialog, mern

I'm having a problem where the button doesn't fire on desktop but it does fire on mobile configuration. My goal is to display a Modal.

Here's the code:

```
function GetData() {
try{
  axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/profile', {
  })
  .then((response)=>{
    const userdata = response.data;
    setUser(userdata)
    console.log(userdata)
  })
  if (User.length > 0){
    try{
      return User.map((user, item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item} style={{ display:'flex', marginTop:'1em',}}>
            <div style={{ marginLeft:'15em', width:'500px'}}>
              <h style={h2}>{user.name}</h>
            </div>
            <div style={{ width:'350px' }}>
              <h style={h2}>{user.email}</h>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button onClick={()=>{setUpdateModal(true);}} className='updateBtn'>UPDATE</button>
            </div>
             {UpdateModal?
            <div style={{ backgroundColor:'white' }}>
             <h>This is a Modal</h>
             </div>
             :null}
          </div>
        )
      })
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
} catch(e){
  console.log(e)
}
}

useEffect(()=> {
GetData()
});
```

And I'm using useState hook.

```
  const [UpdateModal, setUpdateModal] = useState(false)
```

Comment: Can you provide us an exemple ? In addition, be careful with your useEffect. You should set an array of dependency. Here, you may call GetData() on each render (bad practice). See more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html. Use camel case fot the naming of the hook too.

Comment: @RaphaelEscrig  what kind of example?, I did put [ ] in useEffect but that was giving the same result.

Comment: Yes the [] was juste a good practice. The link of your github or an example with https://codesandbox.io/